# tinymce cut/paste plugin

Tags: tinymce

I want to call function after cut/paste event fires.

For example I want to count number of characters entered by user when user do cut/paste in editor via keyboard or mouse (with context menu) also.

Is there any way to call our own function after user do cut/paste ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

Use the [paste plugin](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aPlugins/paste).

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    //mode:'exact',
    mode: "textareas", // none, textareas, exact, ...
    theme: "advanced", // also simple available

    plugins : "paste",

    paste_postprocess : function(pl, o) {

    // o.content holds the pasted content o.content.length will give you the number of characters the user entered
        alert(o.content.length);
    },
```

Comment: hi Thariama

I am using 3.9.2 version of tinymce. there is already built-in paste plugin. i have tried your solution but its giving an error when i am trying to access o.content.length.

is there any change in versions of paste plugin ?

Thanks

Comment: no, there should be no change, but i found a typo in my code - it is corrected now - please try again

Comment: "but i found a typo in my code" what is this ? i am not getting your point. can you please elaborate ?

Comment: "alert(o.content.length);" looked like this before i corrected the error : alert(o.conent.length);

Comment: ohh spelling mistake !!! 
now its working fine. 
Thanks a lot Thariama . 
can we use same thing for cut plugin ?

Comment: glad it works for you now, please keep in mind to vote my post and accept it as accepted solution :)   What do you mwant to achieve with cut?

Comment: i want to achieve same thing.

Comment: hmm, you can only achieve the same thing when you put something from the editor into the clipboard using ctrl+c. in this case you will need to write an own plugin and set tinymce handler for kexboard input listening on ctrl+c - then grab the selected content and return the length

Comment: i want to achieve same thing(char counts)
i am implementing char count entered by user and i have to restrict the user to enter up to certain number of characters(max length).

if you have implemented such kinds of functionality which works properly in every situation like(cut/paste done by keyboard/mouse) then let me know.

Comment: as far as i remember there is a 3rd party plugin for that - but i wasn't able to find it. You may have a look at this thread from the tinymce forum describing various ways: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=3273